# Understanding the quality of the KMeans algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-mining, k-means

After reading [Unbalanced factor of KMeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235576/unbalanced-factor-of-kmeans), I am trying to understand how this works. I mean, from my examples, I can see that the less the value of the factor, the better the quality of KMeans, i.e. the more balanced are its clusters. But what is the naked mathematical interpretation of this factor? Is this a known quantity or something?

---

Here are my examples:

```
C1 = 10
C2 = 100

pdd = [(C1,10), (C2, 100)]
n = 2        <-- #clusters
total = 110  <-- #points
uf = 10 * 10 + 100 * 100
uf = 100100 * 2 / 12100 = 16.5
```

---

```
C1 = 50
C2 = 60

pdd = [(C1, 50), (C2, 60)]
n = 2        
total = 110  
uf = 2500 + 3600
uf = 6100 * 2 / 12100 = 1.008
```

---

```
C1 = 1
C2 = 1

pdd = [(C1, 1), (C2, 1)]
n = 2       
total = 2
uf = 2
uf = 2 * 2 / 2 * 2 = 1
```

Comment: It has been suggested that the likelihood of getting a good answer quickly would be greater on [stats.se]. The question is on topic on both sites, as far as I can tell, so it won't be migrated unless you request a migration. If you would like it to be migrated, just flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find any *scientific* reference for this, not just another stackoverflow question. It may then reveal the theory behind the equation. Because to me it looks very heuristic. I'have never seen it before, and I've read tons of literature.

It appears to be related to Gini index, a measure of entropy, which also uses the sum of squared counts.

There is no indication how this could be *optimized*. As is, I assume this is a penalty factor for model selection. It does not solve the problem that k-means costs improves with k; so it will still prefer the solutions with larger k.

But **why should clusters be balanced**? Most data sets are not balanced.